# New Ubuntu 20.04 New Comcast Router Netgear extender not working

Tags: 20.04, netgear

I updated to Ubuntu 20.04 down in South Carolina and my NetGear N300 extender worked with the Spectrum router in Ubuntu 20.04 boot.  Now moved back to Philadelphia and with new router from Comcast.  I can connect to extender perfectly in my Windows boot but there is question mark in Ubuntu 20.04 boot and cannot connect to any webpages.  Doesn't work in Ubuntu.  It has to be an Ubuntu 20.04/Comcast router/NetGear combination issue as Ubuntu 20.04/Spectrum router/NetGear and Windows/Comcast router/NetGear work both worked.

Here is end of syslog:

```
Nov  1 12:34:56 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC avahi-daemon[699]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address 2601:48:4302:6dd0:f505:557f:35df:71c6.
Nov  1 12:34:56 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC avahi-daemon[699]: Registering new address record for 2601:48:4302:6dd0:f505:557f:35df:71c6 on wlo1.*.
Nov  1 12:34:56 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC avahi-daemon[699]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::c255:4ab6:e6a:3e97 on wlo1.
Nov  1 12:34:56 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC whoopsie[1353]: [12:34:56] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov  1 12:34:56 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[3931]: <info>  [1604252096.5951] dhcp6 (wlo1): option dhcp6_name_servers   => '2001:558:feed::1 2001:558:feed::2'
Nov  1 12:34:56 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[3931]: <info>  [1604252096.5951] dhcp6 (wlo1): option ip6_address          => '2601:48:4302:6dd0::8777'
Nov  1 12:34:56 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[3931]: <info>  [1604252096.5951] dhcp6 (wlo1): state changed unknown -> bound
Nov  1 12:34:56 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC whoopsie[1353]: [12:34:56] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov  1 12:34:56 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC avahi-daemon[699]: Registering new address record for 2601:48:4302:6dd0::8777 on wlo1.*.
Nov  1 12:34:57 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC whoopsie[1353]: [12:34:57] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov  1 12:34:58 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[3931]: <info>  [1604252098.2080] device (wlo1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  1 12:34:58 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[3931]: <info>  [1604252098.2106] device (wlo1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  1 12:34:58 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[3931]: <info>  [1604252098.2109] device (wlo1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  1 12:34:58 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[3931]: <info>  [1604252098.2114] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Nov  1 12:34:58 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[3931]: <info>  [1604252098.2135] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Nov  1 12:34:58 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[3931]: <info>  [1604252098.2136] policy: set 'MCBS1_EXT' (wlo1) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Nov  1 12:34:58 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[3931]: <info>  [1604252098.2143] device (wlo1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov  1 12:34:58 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC nm-dispatcher[5432]: postconf: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Nov  1 12:34:58 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC avahi-daemon[699]: Registering new address record for 2601:48:4302:6dd0:e66b:cec5:3ae:1c70 on wlo1.*.
Nov  1 12:34:59 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC whoopsie[1353]: [12:34:59] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov  1 12:34:59 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC systemd-resolved[647]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Nov  1 12:34:59 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC whoopsie[1353]: [12:34:59] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov  1 12:35:01 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC CRON[5441]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

Comment: Is this a Wifi connection or an Ethernet one?

Comment: Wifi connection.  There is really strong signal showing but just shows question mark and cannot connect to anything.  I added  end of log with trying to connect.  I also updated to latest kernel 5.9.3 and still issue

Comment: Have you already deleted and re-added the network in your network manager?

Comment: You mean forget connection and then connect again?  if so then yes

Comment: You're not getting an ipv4 address. If you UNPLUG the Netgear extender, and connect directly to the Comcast, does it work, or work differently? When you first re-connected the extender, did you reprogram it for the new Comcast wi-fi?

Comment: When I plug extender through Ethernet directly to router it will work.  Yes I did a factory reset of the extender for the new Comcast router.